# Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ where $K $ is splitting field of $x^{12} -3 $

Tags: galois-theory

I am trying to find the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ where $K$ is the splitting field of $x^{12}-3$ and how it acts on the roots of $x^{12} - 3$.

I was able to show that the degree of the Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is 24 and I know that the roots of the given polynomial are $3^{1/12}, w_{12}3^{1/12}, w^2_{12}3^{1/12}, ... ,w^{11}_{12}3^{1/12}$ where $w_{12}^{12} = 1$. However, from here I am lost, I don't know how deduce the structure of the Galois group and how it acts on the roots. Thanks for any hint or help on this problem!

Comment: First, how did you get that degree? Second, can you see what the form of root of unity of degree $\;12\;$ has? Perhaps you need to work a little with the fitting cyclotomic polynomial, which is of degree $\;\phi(12)=4\;$ ...

Comment: Well, first you identify the roots of unity in your field, which should give you a subextension of degree four. Since the whole mess is ramified only at two and three, I think all you need to do is find the additional ramification above three.

Comment: @Lubin, I think talking about "ramification" may be a little overkill and above the level of this question...

Comment: So to get the degree, I showed that the splitting field was $\mathbb{Q}[3^{1/2}, w_{12}]$ and then as you say, we know that the minimal polynomial of $w_{12}$ is of degree 4 and since $3^{1/12}$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial $x^6-3$ in $\mathbb{Q}[w_{12}]$ then the degree of the whole splitting field is at most 24. Then I did a similar process to find the lower bound to be 24 too.

Comment: @user110320 Are you sure $3^{\frac 1{12}}$ satisfies $x^6-3$?

Comment: In accordance with @DonAntonio’s cogent stricture, let me say, in more down-to-earth language, that you can probably get away by adjoining suitable low-order roots of three.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it satisfies the equation $x^6 - \sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let $\zeta_{12}$ be a 12-th root of unity. Then it's not hard to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$. Thus we have that:

$$\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{12}, \sqrt[12]{3}\right) = \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{3},i,\sqrt[12]{3}\right) = \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3},i\right)$$

Now as $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right)$ is a real subfield we have that $i \not \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right)$ and thus $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3},i\right):\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right)\right]=2$. From here we get the Galois group is of order $24$. This seems to be the easiest way, as proving that $x^6 - \sqrt{3}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{12}\right)$ isn't that easy (at least for me). Moreover writing the splitting field as $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3},i\right)$ gives us two linearly independent subfields $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\left(i\right)$ and this can help us with determining the automorphisms.

Now because of the linear independence we can easily write all $24$ automorphisms. They are all of the form:

$$\sigma_{a,b}: \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[12]{3} \to \zeta_{12}^a\sqrt[12]{3}\\
       i \to (-1)^bi
     \end{array}$$

Now note that $\sigma_{1,0}$ has order $12$ and $\sigma_{0,1}$ has order $2$. Also we have:

$$ \sigma_{0,1}\circ \sigma_{1,0} \circ \sigma_{0,1}(i) = \sigma_{1,0}^{-1}(i)$$
$$ \sigma_{0,1}\circ \sigma_{1,0} \circ \sigma_{0,1}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right) = \sigma_{0,1}\left(\zeta_{12}\sqrt[12]{3}\right) = \sigma_{0,1}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{i}{2}\right)\sqrt[12]{3}\right) $$
$$= \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{i}{2}\right)\sqrt[12]{3} = \zeta_{12}^{11}\sqrt[12]{3} = \sigma_{11,0}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right) = \sigma_{1,0}^{-1}\left(\sqrt[12]{3}\right)$$

Thus we get the relation $\sigma_{0,1}\circ \sigma_{1,0} \circ \sigma_{0,1}= \sigma_{1,0}^{-1}$ and this is exactly the relation that characterizes the dihedral group of order $24$. Thus we have:

$$\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong D_{12}$$

Comment: Looks right to me. Maybe it would have been more fun to let OP work out the details.

Comment: @Lubin You could be right. However after solving the problem on my own I though that spotting the Galois group to be $D_{12}$ isn't an easy task, so I added a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Stefan! I didn't notice that $\mathbb{Q}(w_{12}, 3^{1/12}) = \mathbb{Q}(3^{1/2},i)$ and I think that would have been easier to conclude. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user110320 You are welcome :)

Comment: As for proving that $X^6-\sqrt3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3\,)$, you need only know that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3\,]$ is PID and UFD (class number is one). {Easily proved with standard tools, but you do need to know’em}. Then $\sqrt3$ is a prime element, apply Eisenstein and away we go.

Comment: @Lubin Yeah, but he actually claims to have proved it over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$. I can't see an easy way of doing this. Also how does this help us with detemining the degree of the splitting field? I mean we need to adjoin $\sqrt[12]{3}$ and the sixth root of unity. So again it reduces to showing that the sixth root of unity isn't contained in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{3})$, which is what I proved.

Comment: You did it the right way, I think—my suggestion to look first at the cyclotomic subfield was a red herring. But you can prove the irreducibility of $X^6-\sqrt3$ over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{12})$ also by passing to the completion, where your base is still biquadratic, and $\sqrt3$ is still a prime element. (Not that that would have helped much.)

Comment: @AdamCartisano We have that $\sigma_{1,0}(\sqrt[12]{3}) = \zeta_{12}\sqrt[12]{3}$. Hence $\sigma_{1,0}^k(\sqrt[12]{3}) = \zeta_{12}^k\sqrt[12]{3}$. The smallest integer $k$ s.t. $\zeta_{12}^k = 1$ is $12$. Finally,

$$\sigma_{1,0}^{12}(\sqrt[12]{3}) = \zeta_{12}^{12}\sqrt[12]{3} = \sqrt[12]{3}$$
$$\sigma_{1,0}^{12}(i) = (-1)^0i = i$$

Hence $\sigma_{1,0}$ has order 12.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Simple question I couldn't figure it out : How you can affirm with certainty that the 24 you wrote are truly automorphism of that Galois group you are considering? Thanks